# Not getting correct index for the char in String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, indexing, char

I have a string like "What is it in rain"

I need to add blink under each character that needs to be typed through keyboard.
So I find the character using [characterAtIndex]..

But when I reach to the i in 'it' find the index of i using [characterAtIndex:i], it returns 5.
which has to be 8 in the string.

How to get the correct index of next repeated character in a string?

Code:

```
- (int) getCurrentIndexOfChar : (unichar)c instring : (NSString *)str {
      for (int i = 0; i<=[str.length]; i++) {
         if(c == [str characterAtIndex:i]) {
             if (previousChar == c){    //I check here for previous character 
                  return i+1;           //If the previous character is same as next I increment index
             } else {
                  return i;
             }
             previousChar = c;
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: post your code.......

Comment: @Vikas do you mean when you type i, all i of string should be found ?

Comment: @Bhargavi No not all. Only the next character. suppose i have typed upto "What is" noe i have to type 'i' char in 'it'... the above code finds the i ndex 5...which needs to be 8..in the string

Comment: @CodaFi right indexOfCharacter:

Comment: @Vikas Why you are not using **rangeOfString:** ?

Comment: @Bhargavi Please tell me how to achieve the above problem with the rangeOfSString? with code.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this way

```
NSString *main = @"This is it in rain";
NSString *search = @"This is i";
NSLog(@"Index: %d",[main rangeOfString:search].location+[search length]-1);
```

Here you can replace *search* with the text inputed by user.

Comment: So this will give me the index of 'i' in it? Will this work for single word "ingredient" ? Where I have to get the index of second i in the string.

Comment: Yes just give it a try with diff testcase and do some work around if need.

Comment: When i type any character i get the remaining characters left in string. like strLeft = @"in rain" if I type "t" Not the typed characters. Can we modify the code according to it?

Comment: As you want to show blink under typed char, you need to use whole string entered by user as search string. then this will work.

Comment: When i type upto "This is", I got the remaining string like "it in rain". Can we modify the above code with this possibility using remaining string to get the current index?